# Array of 2 button to add at view

Tags: xcode, swift3

```
func addStartingButtons2() {

        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: buttonY, width: 250, height: 30))

        button.layer.cornerRadius = 10  // get some fancy pantsy rounding
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        button.setTitle("Button for Villain: \(String(describing: hashes[button]))", for: UIControlState.normal) 

        buttons.append(button)
        buttons.append(button)

        for button in buttons {
            self.view.addSubview(button)
            button.frame.origin.y += 50
        }
    }
```

Where:
`var hashes = [UIButton : [Double]]()
    var buttons = [UIButton]()`

Want to add this function 2 same buttons one onder other, but only one button is realised

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well yeah, you are trying to add the same button twice.

I didn't test the code but you should be able to do this by putting the logic in a for loop and adding a bit of padding between the buttons, otherwise you will see them overlapping.

Something like this:

```
func addStartingButtons2() {

    for villain in villains { // this depends on your needs, it's just an example

        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: buttonY, width: 250, height: 30))

        // Add offset for the next button.
        buttonY += 40

        button.layer.cornerRadius = 10  // get some fancy pantsy rounding
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        button.setTitle("Button for Villain: \(String(describing: hashes[button]))", for: UIControlState.normal)

        buttons.append(button)
    }

    for button in buttons {
        self.view.addSubview(button)
        button.frame.origin.y += 50
    }

    // If you want to avoid the second loop
    // you can just put view.addSubview(button) inside the first for loop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't work. Your array `buttons` is storing a reference of your button, so you are actually putting two references into the array.

To see the result by yourself, put a break point in your loop and you will see the button with same address twice.

[image]

If you want to have multiple buttons, you have to create them one by one.